# Update Pidgin using apt-get

Tags: apt

How do i update only pidgin using apt-get?

I tried

```
> sudo apt-get update pidgin
```

but i get

```
> The update command takes no arguments
```

Comment: What version of Pidgin do you have now?

Comment: i have version 2.10.3

Comment: For those still interested in using the most recent version of Pidgin, see [this link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/03/how-to-install-pidgin-2-12-in-ubuntu-16-04-via-ppa/)

Answer (score 8):

To update Pidgin to 2.10.7, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pidgin-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pidgin
```

Comment: If you are behind a proxy add -E to sudo so apt-get picks up the http_proxy env vars.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44122/upgrade-a-single-package-with-apt-get) answer by Peachy

> sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install pidgin

Answer (score 1):

As [man apt-get](http://man.cx/apt-get) describes it, `apt-get update` will *resynchronize the package index files from their sources* while `apt-get upgrade` will *install the newest versions of all packages currently installed on the system from the sources enumerated* in your package list aforementioned.

As described in other answers, if you want a newest version than the one in standard packages of your distribution, you have to either edit your sources lists, add a new PPA, install from more recent binaries or compile from source.