# How to update LibreOffice?

Tags: upgrade, libreoffice

I am using Ubuntu 13.10. Is there a way to update LibreOffice? I don't mean remove this version and do a fresh install of a new version! I don't want to waste my internet. I want to just update it.

Comment: Update to what? And how did you install it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upgrade a single package using apt-get?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/44122/how-to-upgrade-a-single-package-using-apt-get)

Comment: I would disagree about this question being a duplicate. It asks a more specific question about LibreOffice. one of the answers below definitely helped me.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely not a single package: it's an entire suite of numerous packages, interestingly *none of which is called exactly* `libreoffice`; they are like `libreoffice-core`, `libreoffice-common`, `libreoffice-gnome`, and many more. For a non-poweruser it's not entirely trivial which one of those should one give as argument for `apt install --only-upgrade`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update LibreOffice in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362690/how-to-update-libreoffice-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 6):

Run the below command on terminal to update `libre-office`,

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Comment: (Thanks & sorry) will the update be a secure way ? or it may cause some problem and performance issues ?

Comment: It is the secure way of updating a software `sudo apt-get install packagename`.

Comment: yes i know this way is secure but i asked about something else ,come on ,its not very important ! THANKS A LOT for supporting.

Comment: and also is it now install the latest version (4.1.3)? i think this this official way only installs Latest LTS release , for example if you install a program with this way and go to official site of that program you can found newer releases there ! so it doesn’t help me !

Answer (score 5):

Add the following command line on the terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Nice that got up up to version 5!

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add the LibreOffice 5 PPA specifically. (For a different version, substitute a different number in for 5.0.)

```
sudo add-apt-repository PPA:libreoffice/libreoffice-5.0
```

Press Enter when prompted to add the repository as a source.

Then, you need to get the latest package lists, including the fresh ones from that source you just added, using...

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you can upgrade LibreOffice automatically.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Hope that helps!