# How to update LibreOffice in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, updates, libreoffice

In Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, for general use, how to update LibreOffice from the default version installed by Canonical?

Are there reasons to leave it as is?
I regularly use Software Updater to install recommended updates, and wonder why LibreOffice is still on an older version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Answer (score 18):

It is opinion-based, but having newer version of LibreOffice is IMHO good because of new features.

To install newer LibreOffice you have to use their [official PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elibreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=focal):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # to get newest dependencies for sure
```

As the result you will get 7.1.6 (at time of writing) instead of [default 6.4.7](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/libreoffice).

Note: reverting to default version is possible by `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:libreoffice/ppa` .

Comment: for some odd reason, when I first installed LO on 20.04 I added the repo `ppa:libreoffice/ppa libreoffice-7-0` and that's where it remains. Will your command `ppa-purge ppa:libreoffice-7-0/ppa` remove it to be followed by `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa` followed by the other two lines restore good order or should I just uncheck the ppa in `Software & Updates` and then install the simpler `ppa:libreoffice/ppa` as outlined?

Comment: Running `sudo ppa-purge ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-7-0` and then `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa` looks good.

Comment: Thanks - done although the old ppa was still listed in `Software & Updates - Other Software` so I just unchecked it.

Comment: ¡last step isn't necessary!
update to new ubuntu version is NOT necessary:
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # to get newest dependencies for sure`