# How to revert to libreoffice 6 from libreoffice 7?

Tags: updates, kubuntu, libreoffice

I wanted to try libreoffice 7, however, the application crashes and it does not open even after running safe mode and restoring the profile This solution I found [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/i-updated-to-7-0-and-now-libreoffice-wont-open-files-or-create-new-file-does-anyone-know-how-i-could-fix-this/55972/4).

I am using kubuntu focal fossa.

I want to go back to the previous version, libreoffice 6. I have tried the following [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362690/how-to-update-libreoffice-in-ubuntu-20-04):

sudo apt-get install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:libreoffice/ppa

But it gave me the following warning:

"PPA to be removed: ppa:libreoffice ppa:libreoffice

Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: ppa:libreoffice ppa:libreoffice"

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Using Ubuntu Software, remove LibreOffice.

Then open "Software & Updates". On the second tab, "Other Software", uncheck the checkmark before both libreoffice PPA's (`https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu...`, one with binary code and one with source code). This inactivates the PPA. You can also fully remove by selecting the PPA and clicking "Remove"

Hit "Close" to close "Software & Updates". This will automatically refresh the software lists.

Reinstall LibreOffice from Ubuntu Software. Make sure you select the older `.deb` version and not the recent `snap` version.

Comment: I have two llibreoffice PPA's, one "main" and the other "main (source code)". None of them are checked by default

Comment: Perfect. The PPA-purge command already removed it. Go ahead with removing LibreOffice and reinstalling it. Make sure NOT to select the SNAP version, and if the SNAP version is installed (which I start to suspect), remove that also.

Comment: do you agree that to remove libreoffice I can do: "sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-core libreoffice-common
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge" and then install it with "sudo apt-get install libreoffice" ?

Comment: Hello, I have tried as described, followinng by downloading a .tar file. Now if I type libreoffice --version it does not appear. But I can open word files. I don't know what happended

Comment: Downloading a .tar file? That is not what I described.

Comment: sorry I don't know where to download that .deb. Anyway I installed it from snap and it worked. Even if it was the v7...

Comment: I did not refer to downloading a deb. I referred to using the Software Center to search the .deb version and install it in the software center. Just a matter of point-and-click.

Comment: My bad. Anyway, thanks