# Libre Office snap - Impress

Tags: video, snap, libreoffice

I have Libre office snap version installed. I don't know why some videos don't play, even though they work fine in the deb version. Videos are within Libreoffice Impress presentations. Libre office version 7.5.4.2. OS Ubuntu 22.4. Both up to date.[picture of snap presentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSJOc.png) The first video does not work, while the second one works without problems. As it was mentioned in deb version there is no problem. Video format first wmv second mp4

Comment: Where are you video files stored?  *snap* packages run confined, thus do **not** have full read access to your real file-system, thus where the files are really matters, and you've not provided us that detail, nor what OS/release you're using.

Comment: You mean videos within Libreoffice Impress presentations?

Comment: Usually, deb packages have less bugs than snaps. Here is how to install the latest version of libreoffice without snaps https://askubuntu.com/a/1362694/124466

Comment: Please edit your question to show us, step-by-step, how to reproduce this issue in a test system.