# How To Apply Wireshark Patch

Tags: patch, wireshark

Running Wireshark Version 1.10.6 (v1.10.6 from master-1.10) on 14.04 LTS.
It crashes anytime i Open a VoIP Graph Flow.

Got the patch at https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9179

Can't figure out how to apply it. Don't know where or what file i should apply it to.

Please help

Comment: Compile from source: https://www.wireshark.org/download/src/ Or, Perhaps upgrade the package?:http://askubuntu.com/questions/44122/how-to-upgrade-a-single-package-using-apt-get

Comment: How to compile from source: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
All I did was to To Install Wireshark 1.12.0 by following the directions in the link below:

http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-wireshark-1-12-0-on-ubuntu-14-04-linux-mint-17-elementary-os-0-3-deepin-2014-and-other-ubuntu-14-04-derivatives/

The new wireshark version is already patched

First of all, i uninstalled the previous wireshark and its dependencies with the autoremove. This "MAY" not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use the patch command to apply the patch.  See the comment I just added to [bug 9179](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9179).