# How to avoid upgrade the package(s) in upgrading?

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade

When I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` some of my installed packages also upgrading, but I don't want to upgrade them. Is there any way to avoid upgrade them.

[Reverse of this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44122/how-to-upgrade-a-single-package-using-apt-get)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can lock a package with

```
sudo apt-mark hold packagename
```

command.

Comment: IS this need to run every time when I want to run upgrade? since I want to avoid upgrade for all time and never upgarde them

Comment: No, you will mark the package as holden until you unhold it (with apt-mark unhold command).

Comment: +1 Thank you. I will check it and after that I will accept. thanks