# How to install RenPy on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, games

This is what I've done:

```
cd Downloads
tar -jxvf renpy-6.99.3-sdk.tar.bz2
./configure
```

And the result was:

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

The renpy-6.99.3-sdk folder contains the following folders:

```
doc launcher lib module renpy renpy.app templates the_question tutorial update
```

And the following archives:

```
LICENSE.txt renpy.exe renpy.py  renpy.sh
```

...

I've tried this:

```
cd Downloads
tar -jxvf renpy-6.99.3-sdk.tar.bz2
cd renpy-6.99.3-sdk
./configure
```

But the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have downloaded is a standalone version of renpy, not a source tarball, so no configuration or build step is required.

You can run it directly using the provided shell script i.e. by cd'ing to the renpy-6.99.3-sdk/ directory and executing `./renpy.sh`

Comment: You're correct!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the apt-get command to install Renpy:

```
sudo apt-get install renpy
```

I hope this is going to help, at least it worked for me :)

Comment: I want to install the latest version.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/44122/how-to-upgrade-a-single-package-using-apt-get