# Update Thunderbird only under Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, thunderbird

I have some custom Nvidia + Cuda drivers installed. I made bad experiences with installing updates under Ubuntu. Several times it broke my system already since the new updates were conflicting with customly installed software. This was especially bad when Ubuntu tried to install / update its own version of the Nvidia drivers while destroying my manually installed ones (Nvida + Cuda 6.5)

Since I don't want to have that experience again: Is there any command of the form

```
sudo apt-get install update for thunderbird only
```

Such that it **only** updates that one program and doesn't effect all the others (just like updating works on Windows).

I googled around and I know that similar questions have been posed, but either the answers don't work or they again recommend installing **all** security updates etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upgrade a single package using apt-get?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/44122/how-to-upgrade-a-single-package-using-apt-get)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade thunderbird` should do the trick