# How do up upgrade LetsEncrypt certbot to version 0.22 which supports wildcard certificates?

Tags: apt, software-installation, ssl, letsencrypt

To get a wildcard SSL certificate from LetsEncrypt you need to run certbot version 0.22 or later according to https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/acme-v2-production-environment-wildcards/55578

I've installed certbot from apt using

```
sudo apt-get install certbot
```

However, that reports:

> certbot is already the newest version (0.17.0-2).

How can I upgrade certbot to a version that supports wildcard certificates?

Answer (score 20):

If you have already installed Certbot, you should add a parameter to apt-get install to upgrade only a specific package

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade certbot
```

Check version number

```
certbot --version || /path/to/certbot-auto --version
```

> Reference answer:
>   [How to upgrade a single package using apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/a/44124)

Comment: When I asked this question, the problem was that apt didn't have the latest version of certbot available.    I'm glad to see that it now has a new enough version to do the DNS verification for wildcard certs.

Answer (score 1):

As [the certbot site indicates](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-other), the certbot team maintains [a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~certbot/+archive/ubuntu/certbot). The `certbot` package is at 0.22.2 on all supported versions of Ubuntu in that PPA. ([What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983/158442))

Answer (score 1):

Check version number:

```
certbot --version
```

> On Ubuntu systems, the Certbot team maintains a [PPA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PPA). You can add it to your list of repositories and install Certbot by running the following commands:
>
> ```sh
> $ sudo apt update
> $ sudo apt install software-properties-common
> $ sudo add-apt-repository universe
> $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
> $ sudo apt install certbot
> ```

<sup>[(source)](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-nginx)</sup>